# Only install packages that are at least X weeks old

Tags: node.js, package-manager, npm

I would like to restrict the installation of npm package in some projects of my company to releases that are at least X weeks old.

The reason for that being that given enough time before installing a package version, it is likely that if the package maintainer was compromised and contains malicious code (in the package itself or in `postinstall` script), it will have been caught and removed from the public npm registry.

I could easily ask our developers to manually install versions that are at least X weeks old, however they are likely to install transitive dependencies that are not locked on a specific version, which can result in the installation of a transitive dependency that is only a few hours old.

Is there a way to force npm to only install packages that are at least X weeks old, including for transitive dependencies ?